# How to use hook in WHMCS only on specific page?

Tags: hook, whmcs

If I want to display sidemenu only on affiliates page (affiliates.php)  than I'm enclosing code in:

```
if (App::getCurrentFilename() == 'affiliates'){

}
```

But how to do same for page `index.php?m=somepage` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the php builtin variables to get the URI, however if you want to use the application object to fetch a specific argument you could do something like:

```
$whmcs = App::self();
$module = $whmcs->get_req_var('m');
```

Comment: All I needed was ``if (App::get_req_var('m') == 'somepage'){ }``  Thank you, you put me in the right direction.

Comment: Btw. Is there anywhere WHMCS manual for those kind of functions?  I couldn't find anywhere

Comment: We have not published full documentation for the Application object. When its done it will be here: http://docs.whmcs.com/classes/index.html